# How to map JSON response to a dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, json

```
{customerCode: "730", accountId: 9, dueAmount: 0, connectionId: 116303, accountName: "Connection"}
```

I have a JSON response like this. I need to add the account accountName to dropdown label and accountId to its curresponding value field.

```
accNames = accNames.filter(function(item, index,inputArray) {
        return inputArray.indexOf(item) == index;
        });
```

I am using the above code to filter the duplicate account names.

```
var sel = document.getElementById('selectAccount');
        for (var i = 0; i < accNames.length; i++) {
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
                opt.innerHTML = accNames[i];
                opt.value = accIds[i];
                sel.appendChild(opt);
        }
```

The above code is used to add the accountName and accountId to dropdown. but the accountName doesn't matches the accountId. There is some problem in mapping accountid to accountname. Anyone please give me some suggestions.

Comment: Your arrays likely have different ordering - it might be wise to sort both of them before performing a synchronised for loop on them in tandem.

Answer (score 0):

If each account name has an associated accountid and it is unique for each accountname you can filter the second array too.

```
accIds = accIds.filter(function(item, index,inputArray) {
        return inputArray.indexOf(item) == index;
        });
```

If an accountname has 2 occurrence its curresponding id also get filtered.